# XPath: How to match a class of characters in an attribute?

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

I have the following XML fragment:

```
...

<Setting name="HOST1">server1</Setting>
<Setting name="HOST2">server2</Setting>
<Setting name="HOST3">server4</Setting>
<Setting name="HOST4">server8n12</Setting>
...
<!-- Many more such declarations all with the attribute of the form "HOSTNN" -->
```

I am using LibXML to find the nodes that match HOST

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xml)
    or die "Unable to create LibXML object";
my $root = $dom->getDocumentElement();

my @hostnames = $root->findnodes('//Setting[contains(@name,"HOST")]');
```

Is it possible to specify a class of characters in an XPath expression similar to what you can specify in a regexp? For example, the Perl regexp:

```
/^HOST\d+?$/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Setting[starts-with(@name,"HOST")]
         [translate(substring-after(@name,"HOST"),
                    "0123456789",
                    "")=""]
```

**Edit**: I didn't see the qualifier. The above will match `Setting[@name="HOST"]`. To be more strict:

```
//Setting[starts-with(@name,"HOST")]
         [number(substring-after(@name,"HOST")) = 
          substring-after(@name,"HOST")]
```

**Edit 2**: The above it's not strict enough (It will match "HOST2.1"). Sorry.

```
//Setting[starts-with(@name,"HOST")]
         [substring-after(@name,"HOST")]
         [translate(substring-after(@name,"HOST"),
                    "0123456789",
                    "")=""]
```

Comment: @Alejandro, will this give a match to hosts where there are two digits after the "HOST" substring?

Comment: @Rob, yes it will. `translate()` replaces all occurrences of any character in the second argument with the corresponding character in the third argument (an empty string in this case). @Alej: +1, good idea.

Comment: Thanks @LarsH and @Alejandro for the original post. +1 to both of you.

Comment: @Rob Wells: @LarsH is right, but an empty string will be translate to an empty string. Check my edit for a more strict expression.

Comment: @Alejandro, cool! Thanks for the update and I'm now using release v3.0! cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My xpath is a bit rusty, but I think this may work (either that or i'm combining my css with xpath)

```
Setting[@name^="HOST"]
```